# GCM related and private IP

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using private IPs, such as `192.168.20.39` and testing GCM android project, I have `RegId` required:

```
com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 401  error.
```

How can I solve this? And can I test with this kind of private IP?

Comment: Post your relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear yet, from what you have asked I assume couple of things.

1. You are trying to implement Push Notifications for Android using GCM and you want to test it locally
2. You are testing it on a device (not emulator) and both your device and development machine are connected to same local network.

If so, Make sure you have added this code to your registration code block

```
Registration regService = new Registration.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                .setRootUrl("http://192.168.20.39:8080/_ah/api/")
                .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                        abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                    }
                }).build();
```

Where, `192.168.20.39` must be the IP of your development PC (If not, change it accordingly).

And in your PC, make sure you are starting the GCM Backend server with a parameter `--address=0.0.0.0`. Adding this will assure the availability of the  server in local network.